# Pattern with colored squares in 3x3 grids

Tags: pattern

This is a question from log 155 test posted on a sub/reddit
https://www.reddit.com/r/cognitiveTesting/comments/115haor/log155_statistics_200_attempts/

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The answer is

> [image]

First step is to realize

> anywhere you see a square with an arrow it implies it has the exact pattern as the square with the same full color. The full color actually represent the last figure of each row (hidden). Also you can see that blue is connected to the white square, red is connected to the light grey square and yellow is connected to bit darker grey square and green is connected to the dark grey square (in other words blue row 1, red row 2, yellow row 3 and green row 4.) Here is an image to illustrate it: 
>  [image]

Now let's solve each row,

> by replacing each full colored (except the last one for now) square with the last figure. There are four different patterns going on. Here are explanations for the patterns:
>  [image]
>  And each square with an arrow changing color of course according to it's row color (which also is implied by the two cells on each side of the arrow).

Lastly

> If we make each row only to consist of their row color (replacing the arrow squares and full colored squares), we get: 
>  [image] 
>  So our answer is **F.**